# Vertical position of minipages in a tabular

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, minipage

I have a problem with the tabular environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\linewidth}
    \fbox{\parbox{4cm}{Texte 1

        Texte 2

        Texte 3}}
  \end{minipage}
  &
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\linewidth}
    \fbox{\parbox{4cm}{Texte 1}}
  \end{minipage}
  &
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\linewidth}
    \fbox{\parbox{4cm}{Texte 1

        Texte 2

        Texte 3

        Texte 4}}    
  \end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I can't find the right options to put in minipage so that the boxes are vertically aligned on their tops.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the correct option for the `minipage`s, they are aligned by the first line of text in them. But the first line has `\parbox`es, and they are centered on the line by default. Hence,  with `\parbox[t]{4cm}{..}` you get what you're after.

But if you only have a `\parbox` in the `minipage`s, then you probably don't need both, so you could remove all the `minipage` environments. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \fbox{\parbox[t]{0.3\linewidth}{Texte 1

        Texte 2

        Texte 3}}
  &
    \fbox{\parbox{0.3\linewidth}{Texte 1}}
  &
    \fbox{\parbox[t]{0.3\linewidth}{Texte 1

        Texte 2

        Texte 3

        Texte 4}}    
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This did the trick.